# For $X,Y $ random variables, $h $ a function, show that $E (Xh(Y)|Y)=h (Y)E (X|Y) $ almost surely

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, random-variables, conditional-expectation

Question in the title:

> For $X,Y $ random variables, $h $ a function, show that $E (Xh(Y)|Y)=h (Y)E (X|Y) $ almost surely

My main problem is that I don't even understand what $E (Xh(Y)|Y)$ means... I know what $E (Xh(Y)|Y=5)$ for example would mean, but without evaluating $Y $ I do not see how to give meaning to the expression. The only thing I could think of would be to consider $E (Xh(Y)|Y)$ as a new r.v. in the r.v.  $Y $. Is this correct?

Comment: See : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation  . This is far from an easy concept to grasp in generality

Comment: Note that we must assume $h$ Borel-measurable for $h(Y)$ to be a random variable and the expression $\mathbb E[Xh(Y)\mid Y]$ to be well-defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $h:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is Borel-measurable, then $h(Y)$ is measurable with respect to the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $Y$: $$\sigma(Y) = \{ Y^{-1}(B):B\in\mathcal B(\mathbb R)\}. $$ It follows from the definition of conditional expectation that
$$\mathbb E[X h(Y)\mid Y] = h(Y)\mathbb E[X\mid Y]$$ with probability one (assuming that $\mathbb E[|Xh(Y)|]<\infty$ and $\mathbb E[|X|]<\infty$).

Comment: One can predict with a high degree of certainty that this does not answer the OP's question. At the same time, since the OP's problem is that they did not check the (full measure-theoretic) definition of conditional expectation before asking... (Note that, to be fully rigorous, one should check that $Xh(Y)$ and $X$ are integrable, not only that $h$ is measurable.)

Comment: @Did Those assumptions are necessary in order for the question to make sense in the first place..

Comment: Sure, all the more reason to state them explicitely in an answer (as you did now) when they are not in the question.