# How can I show that E[Y|X]= X^2

Tags: probability, statistics, conditional-expectation

I have X distributed as a standard normal and $$Y = X^2$$. 
How can I show that $$E[Y|X]= X^2$$

Comment: Isn't it true in general that if $Y=g(X)$ then $E[Y|X] = g(X)$, regardless of the distribution of $X$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$Y=X^2 = X \cdot X$ is measurable as product of $X$ in the $\sigma$-Algebra generated by $X$, therefore $$E[Y\mid X] = Y = X^2$$

Adding a proof for what @MPW has mentioned in the comments, let $X$ and $Z$ be random variables (with discrete values), then for any (Borel-measurable) transformation $g(X)$ it follows that:

$$E[Z\cdot g(X) | X ] = g(X) \cdot E[Z|X]$$

We have to compute the conditional expectation given $X=x$, whereas the value of $Z$ varies over the entire range (here denoted with $z$), therefore:
$$\begin{align*}E[Z\cdot g(X) | X=x ] &=  \sum_{z} zg(x) P(Z=z|X=x)\\
&= g(x) \sum_{z} zP(Z=z|X=x) \\ &= g(x) E[Z|X=x]\end{align*}$$

It follows that $E[Z\cdot g(X)|X] = g(X)E[Z|X]$ with a similar argument for the continous case (see: [For $X,Y $ random variables, $h $ a function, show that $E (Xh(Y)|Y)=h (Y)E (X|Y) $ almost surely](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1870916/for-x-y-random-variables-h-a-function-show-that-e-xhyy-h-ye-xy?rq=1)) and for your exercise $Z = 1$ and the transformation $g$ is squaring.

Comment: Since I have to show it can I use the LIE this way?
$$E [Y|X] = E[E [Y|X]|X]=Y = X^2$$

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with "LIE" but yes you can use the tower property , since $E[Y|X]$ is $X$ measurable, but how do you deduce that $$E[E[Y|X]|X] = Y$$

Comment: Law of iterated expectations

Comment: Alright, so we were talking about the same property. Still you cannot deduce the second equation without using the fact that $Y$ is $X$ measurable.

Comment: Thank you! To show that E[Y]=1 instead?

Comment: You want to show $E[Y]=1$? You should ask that as a different question but here's my hint, you know that $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ and so $$E[Y] = E[X^2] = E[(X-E[X])^2]$$ The last equality is due to $X$ having expected value $0$. Now think if you recognize the last term.